# Erro na máscara e na validação do campo email

Tags: jquery, webforms, input-mask

Estou tentando implementar uma mascara e validar o campo email utilizando o plugin [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) sem sucesso a mascará não aparece e consequentemente não faz validação, por quê ?

**Esse é o código:**

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">   
</asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/jquery-3.3.1.min.js") %>'></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/scripts/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js") %>'></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       (function ($) {
           $(function () {

               $('#txtEmail').inputmask({
                   mask: "*{1,20}[.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}]@*{1,20}[.*{2,6}][.*{1,2}]",
                   greedy: false,
                   onBeforePaste: function (pastedValue, opts) {
                       pastedValue = pastedValue.toLowerCase();
                       return pastedValue.replace("mailto:", "");
                   },
                   definitions: {
                       '*': {
                           validator: "[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-]",
                           casing: "lower"
                       }
                   }
               });
           });
       })(jQuery);

    </script>


    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="txtEmail" class="font-weight-bold">Email</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="50" ToolTip="Digite o Email" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Erro

```
Uncaught TypeError: Inputmask is not a constructor
    at w.fn.init.$.fn.inputmask (jquery.inputmask.js:76)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (CadUsuario.aspx?idusuario=7:259)
    at l (VM792 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (VM792 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Troque o arquivo `jquery.inputmask.js` pelo `jquery.inputmask.bundle.js`

Comment: E o que você quer dizer com máscara para e-mail? quando o script deve saber que precisa inserir um `@` ou um `.`

Comment: @leandro Angelo inserir um @

Comment: @Jorge.M baixei o jqu3ry.inputmask pelo NuGet e não existe esse arquivo jquery.input.bundle.js, o nome desse arquivo tá correto ?